# RecyclerView inside of Fragment only gets populated if adapter and RecyclerView are setup in onCreate

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-dialogfragment

I have a custom DialogFragment that has it's own RecyclerView, and for some reason the data does not get populated unless the adapter/recyclerView logic is performed in `onCreate`.  Nothing will happen if it is called in `onCreateView` or `onViewCreated`, which is where I want all of this logic to happen.  Here is the version that works in onCreate:

```
@Override public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    root = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_content, null);

    ButterKnife.bind(this, root);

    MyAdapter adapter = new MenuOptionsAdapter(getContext(), this);
    adapter.setData(getData());
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

}
```

And here is my try in onCreateView:

```
@Nullable
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
      @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_content, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, root);

    // 'this' in the initialization of MyAdapter represents a custom interface, don't worry about it
    MyAdapter adapter = new MenuOptionsAdapter(getContext(), this);
    adapter.setData(getData());
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
}
```

I tried to initialize root like this as well in onCreateView: `root = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_content, null);`
But no dice.

Does anyone know what could be a possible reason for this? I also tried adding the same exact code in onViewCreated, but again, no luck.

PS - I also tried adding `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after setting the data and also tried it after `rv.setData`.

Comment: how are you displaying the dialog?

Comment: `DialogFragment f = MyDialogFragment.newInstance();
    f.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), DIALOG_TAG);`

Comment: Then you need to use onCreateDialog and supply your own dialog setting your view as its view

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    root = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_content, null, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, root);

    // 'this' in the initialization of MyAdapter represents a custom interface, don't worry about it
    MyAdapter adapter = new MenuOptionsAdapter(getContext(), this);
    adapter.setData(getData());
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
        .setView(root)
        .show();
}
```

Comment: Nope.  Calling `getLayoutInflater().inflate...` causes some type of circular dependency error and the app to crash

Comment: ```at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performGetLayoutInflater(Fragment.java:1221)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getLayoutInflater(Fragment.java:1207)
                                                                             at com.myapp.MyDialogFragment.onCreateDialog(MyDialogFragment.java:120)```

This is printed hundreds of times in the Logcat until the app crashes

Comment: made a small mistake, fixing now

Comment: Also realized i forgot to add Butterknife.bind here too

Answer (score 0):

If you wand to add view from layout, you should pass 'true' to last parametr in method inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_content, container, true);